Conflicting values when using apt update
Can you assist with fixing this error I am getting in bash when using apt update?
(base) alfonso@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ noble-pgdg: /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc != /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.gpg
E: The list of sources could not be read.

I was following the instructions for Postgre
https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/
I think I messed up by running the commands for audtomatd repository configurate:
sudo apt install -y postgresql-common
sudo /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.sh

and the manual configuration
sudo apt install curl ca-certificates
sudo install -d /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg
sudo curl -o /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc --fail https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc] https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install postgresql

